# csv to tsv in python with nested quotes

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a CSV file with lines like this:

```
"AAA","BBB","Test,""Test""","CCC",DDD
"111","222,""333""","XXX","YYY, ZZZ"
```

dealing with nested quotes doesn't provide desired result:

```
AAA    BBB    "Test, ""Test"""    CCC    DDD
111    "222, ""333"""    XXX    YYY, ZZZ
```

desired result:

```
AAA    BBB    Test, "Test"    CCC    DDD
111    222, "333"    XXX    YYY, ZZZ
```

This is what I've tried:

```
csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect='excel-tab').writerows(csv.reader(sys.stdin))
csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect='excel-tab').writerows(csv.reader(sys.stdin, delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))
csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect='excel-tab', delimiter='\t').writerows(csv.reader(sys.stdin, delimiter=',', quotechar='"'))
```

BTW, performance is important.

Comment: The real problem seems to be with the spaces around the commas. Do you really genuinely have a space after each? (Why?)

Comment: nope, good catch

Comment: Your "desired result" is no longer valid CSV really I believe. You could request this with `csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect='excel-tab', csv.QUOTE_NONE)` but you then get an error when you try to write rows which need to be quoted.

Comment: what do you mean by "no longer"? csv format/standard changed?

Comment: It's not like there is _one_ "standard"; this is Microsoft territory.

Comment: OMG I had just found a beautiful solution based on the fact that there were spaces after the commas :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could in theory request this with

```py
csv.writer(sys.stdout, dialect='excel-tab', csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

but then you get an error if you try to output something which Python decides needs to be quoted:

```
_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set
```

You could perhaps define your own [`csv.Dialect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters) but perhaps the easiest solution at this point is to just treat the output as text.

```py
r = csv.reader(sys.stdin)
for row in r:
    sys.stdout.write('\t'.join(row))
    sys.stdout.write('\n')
```

This obviously loses some of the guarantees you get from using a tested and debugged `csv` object, but as you seem to be sure about your requirements, perhaps this is an acceptable simplification.